# Code coming back from script not detected by jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I basically have a div container which i am reusing to fill with different data, depending on the link that is clicked.

This div container has a class name of "test_bed" and the anchors used to populate it have class names of "linkA", "linkb" etc.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.link").click(function(e) {   
    //prevent default behaviour:
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = "a";
    var b = "b";
    //pass vars to script:
    $.post('00_php_script_.php', { x:a , y:b },
    function(output){
      //Replace div content with script output:
      $('div#test_bed"').html(output).show();
    });
  });
});
```

This is one of the "linkA" anchors as mentioned above:

```
<a href="" id="linkA" name="linkA" class="linkA">LinkA</a>
```

All the php script does is echo the vars back along with a link:

```
echo $_POST['x'] . " " . $_POST['y'] . " " . '<a href="" id="linkA" name="linkA" class="linkA">LinkA</a>';
```

Everything works fine, except for the fact that the link, which is returned from the php script into the test_bed div does not seem to be detected by the above jquery code.

QUESTION:

How do I make the code which is returned from the php script be detected by the above jquery code??

Any assistance appreciated guys....

Comment: What do you mean by "detected" exactly? Does "LinkA" show up?

Comment: LinkA appears, but when its clicked, it does not behave as the above function describes, it just acts as a default link.

Comment: When a new element is added to the DOM, it does not automatically have listeners applied to it.  You must use `.live()` or `.delegate()`, or apply the handler to the added link.

Comment: You're applying a jQuery event handler to something that doesn't yet exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> LinkA appears, but when its clicked, it does not behave as the above function describes, it just acts as a default link.

That is because when you define the `click()` event, the definition applies only to those elements that currently exist in the document, not future ones.

Take a look at `.live()` for a workaround. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a.link").live('click', function(e) {
```